# Synchronous access to REST Service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, concurrency, playframework

I am using Play 2 Framework. I would like synchronize access to one of the REST end points. I have never seen usage of synchronize block in REST services. Is it possible? What is correct approach to synchronize in REST service and allow only one thread at the time?

Comment: What should be synchronized where? Do you want to prevent that multiple clients call 1 http method?

Comment: Yes, I have couple calls to database which are not transactional, In between I have some checks and at the end one more save,  so I would like to prevent to access to the method more than one user at the time.

Comment: I suppose you can just add `synchronized` to the method that implements the logic but that's a really bad idea (which is why you don't see it). The correct approach is to design the system so that it works concurrently. With transactions or whatever you'll need.